# В битриксе тормозит  javascript

Tags: javascript, битрикс

Здравствуйте. В битриксе добавил на форму обратный звонок. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку для появления формы, форма либо показывается либо нет. Очищаю кэш и обновляю страницу, форма показывается. Что делать, чтобы не тормозила и без проблем всегда открывалась форма по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: прикольное оформление вопроса, как насчет выложить какойто пример на jsfiddle?

Comment: А что есть здесь прикольного?

Comment: @Hmayak т.е. вопрос выглядит так: у меня не заводится машина, в чем проблема?

Comment: >В битриксе тормозить javascript
================
>добавил форма обратный звонок
================
>чтобы форма появился
================
>без проблем всегда открылся форма 

[эта книга][1] должна помочь


  [1]: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4047057/

Answer (score 1):

Битрикс тут не при чем. Разбирайтесь в коде javascript.

Comment: В строке подключения скрипта добавил defer, и все начал нормально работать.

Comment: Значит проблема в сервере